# electron-builder shows white page after compile

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I trying to build an Electron app. For that I'm using the following respos: 

https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder


In devoplement mode (electron .) everything works fine. But when I build the app and starting it, it just shows me a blank page without any errors in the dev console or build log. 


Why doesn't it work in production? All my files are in one direction:

- index.html
- main.js
- renderer.js
- package.json

I didn't changed much in the base main.js file:

```
  // Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      webSecurity: false
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  //mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your output html in production should be located elsewhere, btw I'm using angular with electron and the output is in the  dist folder, but I don't use url.format: try with `` mainWindow.loadURL(`file://$_dirname/index.html`) ``
or if you have a dist folder `` mainWindow.loadURL(`file://$_dirname/dist/index.html') ``
Try changing also
`app.whenReady()` by `app.on("ready",createWindow)`
Hope it works afterwards